# Selenium IDE - wait command for css

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am using Selenium IDE to record one of my application's authentication. IDE recorded a 'css', **now i want to insert a wait command for it**. This is my script so far.

```
open /my application.index,php
waitForElement id=email
type id=email
waitForElement id=pass
type id=pass
waitforElement id=submit
clickAndWait id=submit
clickAndWait css=div.lang-flag
```

(Once logged in, i am clicking on a language hyperlink to change the language. This is where i need to place a wait command)

**Can someone please help?**

Comment: waitForElementPresent should work.

Comment: Thanks.. It worked. However, i am using a tool called Qualys to perform a security scanning of my web application. The credentials needs to be passed as a selenium script. I have uploaded the same script above to the Qualys tool. But this script fails to recognize waitForElementPresent for this css.. Any idea on this ?

Comment: See what other waitFors they allow.

Comment: The tool did accept the waitFors for email and password but not for this css

Comment: That is odd. Ok, well try it with an Xpath then. I'd also reach to their tech support.

Comment: Ok will try with Xpath. Thanks DMart.

Comment: Tried with Xpath.. but stil not working :(

Comment: what is the error you get from them? Does it just fail? Or not find the element? It might be how they're running it in another browser, or pseudo browser so the element never exists, or does the command fail as unsupported?